# Migration of a project from Maven to gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I cannot perform the `gradle init` command in the directory of the project: the command line show this error :

```
gradle is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 operable program or batch file
```

should I insert gradle as an environmental variable ? if so, how?

Comment: this indicates, that you just havn't installed gradle properly. Have a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html for the details.

Comment: @ReneGroeschke Ok, I tried to add gradle dir to the enviroment variable but the same error still appear:

Comment: you need to setup the PATH properly too. you can also use tools like SDKMAN (http://sdkman.io) to install Gradle easily.